# Progress bar not refreshing in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have a problem, I am using `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()` in on button_click method, and using `backgroundWorker1_DoWork()`, `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged()` events also, all events are triggering but progress bar is not refreshing. here is my code :

```
private void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
           {

               backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

                for (int i = 0; i < gdFiles.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    // my process
                 }

              catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
     }
```

And events are

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {

                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }


        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            progressBar1.Refresh();
        }
```

Can any one please help on this.....

Comment: Try removing `progressBar1.Refresh();` from `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` event

Comment: I have already tried without progressBar1.Refresh(); initially, even though not getting....

Comment: maybe `// my process` blocks UI for 10 sec? so you only see 0% and 100% ?

Comment: Did you set `backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true` as suggested by Garath below

Comment: exactly, my process has file moving logic , its blocking winfrom.. Any solution now please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress` it should be set to true. Bellow working and tested example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {

            bw.ReportProgress(i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate your problem and it works fine on my end. Make sure backgroundWorker1.ReposrtsProgress is set to **True**. See code below:

```
   'private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressBar1.Refresh();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }`
```

Also, I think your "process" should be inside DoWork.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you move your filemoving logic to the DoWork part? The idea of a BackgroundWorker is to remove the heavy stuff from the UI-thread.